# GKSession Bluetooth connection problems

Tags: ios, bluetooth, gksession, dns-sd

My goal is to create a client/server Bluetooth game with 1 master and 1..6 clients. Devices are iPads v.2-4 with iOS 6+.

First realization of this task was using GKSession class with client/server model. GSSession implementation shawn that this class contains many problems with server detection by clients,  is unstable when 4+ devices are connected and so on.

Ok, i refused of using GKSession and redesigned network classes to work with DNSSD-api server publishing over Bluetooth and CFSockets. This realization also shew clients errors of server spotting and connection problems.

I have now an idea of creating for each client iPad a GKSession object with it's unique SessionID and implent an array of GKSessions on server iPad - so each client will operate with it's own GKSession.

Can someone give me an advice how should i create stable connection with 7 iPads over bluetooth and what do you think am i doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if you're still looking into this but now that iOS 7 is out, have you checked out the Multipeer Connectivity framework and in particular `MCSession`?

Comment: I have already implemented, as i said, using GKSession, but, unfortunately, GKSession is now deprecated in iOS 7. May be some code with GKSession implementation will be helpful: https://github.com/vbrylinskiy/GKSessionWrappers